# Handle orientation changes in baidu maps

Tags: android, baidu, baidu-map

What is the correct way to handle orientation changes in Baidu Maps?

There seems to be no getter or setter to get the center and zoom level or the bounds of the currently shown map.

Comment: This is just a test. Please upvote this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to save the state is `onSaveInstanceState(...)` callback. I wrote this code here:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("map", mapView.getMap().getMapStatus());
}
```

When you want to recover the data try this example (taken from a fragment):

```
@Nullable
@Override
public synchronized View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.baido_map, container, false);
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.baido_map);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mapView.getMap().setMapStatus(MapStatusUpdateFactory.newMapStatus(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("map")));
    }

    return view;
}
```